# Is it not possible to specify one and infer one type in a generic function

Tags: typescript

So I would like one type to be specified by the user but the other to be inferred from the argument

simplest example

```
export function state<D, T extends string = string>(type: T) {
  return [] as Array<D | T> 
}

var b = state<number>('fooBarTest'); // (string, number)[]
```

I would like typeof b to equal

```
var b = state<number>('fooBarTest') // (number | "fooBarTest")[]`
```

without needing to write

```
var b = state<number, 'fooBarTest'>('fooBarTest') // (number | "fooBarTest")[]`
```

Is it possible?